# nmap ciphers scanning result is inconsistent

Tags: linux, nmap, 3des

I am working on preventing SWEET32 Attack. I have disabled weak ciphers. When I run the below comments multiple times.

```
nmap -p 443 --script ssl-enum-ciphers example.com
```

I am getting inconsistent results. Can any one explain me, "How to get constant results?". TIA.